# How to set the background colour of a checked toggle button in Avalonia UI Desktop application

Tags: togglebutton, avaloniaui

I am trying to set the background colour of a checked toggle button in Avalonia UI.

The following style sets the padding of all checked toggle buttons within the user control to 40, but the background colour remains the default blue instead of red.

```
    <UserControl.Styles>
        <Style Selector="ToggleButton:checked">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="40"/>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Styles>
```

Here is an example where "Option 1" is checked.

[image]

How can I override the default background colour of a checked toggle button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Pseudoclasses on the button your selector has to target the ContentPresenter on the button template.

```xml
<Style Selector="ToggleButton">
  <!-- Default setters here -->

  <Style Selector="^:checked /template/ ContentPresenter#PART_ContentPresenter">
    <!-- Checked setters here -->
  </Style>
</Style>
```

Optionally you can leave off `#PART_ContentPresenter`, but that will target any content presenter on the control so be careful doing that.  In the default template the button only has one.

Comment: Thank you. Now I know what I’m looking for I can see it’s in the Avalonia UI docs. It also says you can use pointerover instead of checked in the selector. Do you know the syntax for setting the style when the toggle button is both checked and the pointer is over?

Comment: @BenHarden The pseudoclasses can be stacked so just add `:checked:pointerover`

Comment: Amazing, thanks